# Selecting ROI in Auto Resized Window

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to select a Region of Interest using cv2.selectROI() by using a namedWindow("name",**WINDOW_AUTOSIZE**)

But when I select the ROI I cannot visualize the box.

With namedWindow("name",**WINDOW_NORMAL**) the box is visible, it works.

```
if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Read image
    im = cv2.imread("386368.jpg")

    showCrosshair = False
    fromCenter = False
    cv2.namedWindow("Image",2)
    r = cv2.selectROI("Image", im, fromCenter, showCrosshair)
    cv2.waitKey(30)
```

Same problem when I use cv2.resize() too.
Should I increase the waitKey value? or How can I solve this issue.

[image: This is the auto resized window though I am actually dragging I cannot visualize the ROI]
[image: This is the normal window I can see the blue box]

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not enough. This is my result and code.

---

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2017.11.28 14:32:33 CST

import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    # Read image
    img = cv2.imread("test.png")
    cv2.namedWindow("Image",2)
    roi = cv2.selectROI("Image", img, False, False)

    ## Display the roi
    if roi is not None:
        x,y,w,h = roi
        mask = np.zeros_like(img, np.uint8)
        cv2.rectangle(mask, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,255,255), -1)
        masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask )
        cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
        cv2.imshow("ROI", masked)

    cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser but cv2.selectROI lets you draw a blue box I don't get that box if I resized the window.

Comment: @janu777 I try to resize the `Image` window on my PC, it's OK.

Comment: Yeah for some images the resizing works but for some images it doesn't.

Comment: ... I just tested the one. Then I have no idea why.